# Using HtmlWebpackPlugin with inject = true does not minify ES6 code

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, minify

I am trying to create a html file from a template file, injecting some JavaScript inline into the html file.

This works great, other than when I get to some ES6 syntax in my js file async in particular in my example.  It then leaves all the code unminified in that particular block of code.

I was wondering if there is a way to transpile my code perhaps before it gets minified?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My webpack.config.js file looks as follows

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Uglify = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './TestFile/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'TestFile')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'TestFile.html',
            template: './TestFile/TestFileTemplate.html',
            inject: true,
            jquery: fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/jquery.js', 'utf8'),
            gds: fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/extras.js', 'utf8'),
            style: fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/css/style.css', 'utf8'),
            minify: {
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributese: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: use preset-env and other plugins depending on the features you are looking to transpile.

Comment: Do you have an example of this by any chance? I don’t really quite know what you mean “and other plugins”? Thanks

Comment: https://babeljs.io/
All depends on your needs. This is what you have to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to minify the file here:

```
gds: fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/extras.js', 'utf8'),
```

You can use babel to transpile the file content:

```
gds: require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/extras.js', 'utf8'), {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}).code;
```

There is also `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin`. It might be a cleaner way to inline files.